# Statistical summary using QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, vector, batch

I have 15 layers and I click on "show statistical summary" to calculate the same field for each layer.

Is there any method to calculate all of them at once rather than doing it one by one?

Comment: There is a tool called `Basic statistics for fields` that can be run as a batch process.

Comment: i tried it , always gives me errors, it runs well when it's done one by one

Comment: What is the statistics you want to calculate, sum/mean/? ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As was mentioned by @Matt there is corresponding algorithm for that i.e. ["Basic statistics for fields"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoranalysis.html#basic-statistics-for-fields), that can be launched from Python Console using PyQGIS.

Let's assume there are two layers *'groupe_layers'* and *'groupe_layers_copy'* with corresponding attribute tables, see image below.

[image: input]

My target field is the `"AREA_HA"` for which the basic statistics must be calculated.

Proceed with `Plugins > Python Console > Show Editor` and paste the script below

```py
field_name = "AREA_HA" # target field

layers = ['groupe_layers', 'groupe_layers_copy'] # target layers

output_path = 'C:/TempDaten/' # location for storing temporal files

for layer in layers:
    processing.run("qgis:basicstatisticsforfields", {
        'INPUT_LAYER' : layer,
        'FIELD_NAME' : field_name,
        'OUTPUT_HTML_FILE' : output_path + layer + '.html'
        })
```

Press `Run script` [image: run script] and get the output that will look like (openned in Chrome)

[image: result]

Afterwards you may parse your HTML files to get the desired values.

Comment: there are 15 layers and I want to show the length of each layer individually in one step rather than iterating the same process for each layer, I hope you get it

Answer (score 1):

You can try to merge the layers and then calculate the statistical summary